# Is ngsi10 convenience operations recommended to create entities?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

In Fiware, entities are identified by two fields: entityId + entityType. This means that you can have multiple entities with the same entityId while its have differents entityType.

Said that:

-How it is accepted to create entities using ngsi10 convenience operations in which entities are created with an empty entityType field?

-Is it unrecommended to created entities that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to create entities using convenience operations. [A section in the manual](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Convenience_Entity_Creation) describes the topic. In this sense, it is as recommended as creating entities using standard operations is.

In fact, Orion is quite flexible and there are 3 ways of doing that:

- Using `POST /v1/contextEntities/Room1`. The entity ID is specified in the URL, the entity type is "empty type" (i.e. "").
- Using `POST /v1/contextEntities/type/Room/id/Room1` (since Orion 0.16.0). Both entity ID (Room1) and type (Room) are specified in the URL.
- Using `POST /v1/contextEntities` (since Orion 0.17.0). In this case both entity ID and type are specified in the payload.